# Can't subtract from the row/column of a 2d array.[Java]

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a knight's tour program but when I try to subtract from the row/column in the 2d array for the board so I move around the board. But everything I try to do it keeps trying to set the board to -1 instead of subtracting 1.

Kind of hard to explain what the problem is, but if anyone could help me out here that would be well appreciated here's my code:

```
public class Knight1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int board[][] = new int[8][8];
        int horizontal[] = new int[8];
        int vertical[] = new int[8];

        horizontal[0] = 2;
        horizontal[1] = 1;
        horizontal[2] = -1;
        horizontal[3] = -2;
        horizontal[4] = -2;
        horizontal[5] = -1;
        horizontal[6] = 1;
        horizontal[7] = 2;

        vertical[0] = -1;
        vertical[1] = -2;
        vertical[2] = -2;
        vertical[3] = -1;
        vertical[4] = 1;
        vertical[5] = 2;
        vertical[6] = 2;
        vertical[7] = 1;
        int move = 1;

        int moveNumber = 0;
        int currentRow = 0;
        int currentCol = 0;
        int counter = 1;

        while (moveNumber != 7) {
            currentRow += vertical[moveNumber];
            currentCol += horizontal[moveNumber];
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = counter;
            moveNumber++;
            counter++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say currentRow += vertical[moveNumber]; currentRow equals to -1. And then you want to board[currentRow][currentCol] = counter; but currentRow is -1, so you cant do this. I didn't understand what do you want to do?

Comment: In other words, you can't have an Array index value less than **0** or an Array index value greater than the number of elements contained within the Array -1.

Comment: Side note. You can initialize arrays like this: `int[] vertical = new int[]{-1, -2, ... 1};`

Comment: board[-1] or board[-2] has no array index array start from 0 index.

Answer (score 0):

Problem come up on this point:

```
   int currentRow = 0;
   int currentCol = 0;
```

You are trying to add **-1** to **currentRow** variable

```
    vertical[0] = -1;
    currentRow += vertical[moveNumber];
```

I just look at Knight's tour problem and your code. If I understood both of them correctly, you should start from **ROW 7** and **COLUMN 4**.

So only change this two variable:

```
    int currentRow = 7;
    int currentCol = 4;
```

It is going to compile this result:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 
0 0 5 0 0 0 3 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 6 0 0 0 0 0 2 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 7 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I also edited your main method a little bit:
You don't need to horizontal and vertical arrays. You can do it with multi-dimensional arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int board[][]  = new int[8][8];
        int moveNumber = 0;
        int currentRow = 7;
        int currentCol = 4;
        int counter    = 1;

        //moves[moveNumber][0] = columnValues;
        //moves[moveNumber][1] = rowValues;
        int moves[][] = new int[][]{{ 2,-1},
                                    { 1,-2},
                                    {-1,-2},
                                    {-2,-1},
                                    {-2, 1},
                                    {-1, 2},
                                    { 1, 2},
                                    { 2, 1}};

        while (moveNumber != 7) {
            currentCol += moves[moveNumber][0];
            currentRow += moves[moveNumber][1];
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = counter;
            moveNumber++;
            counter++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a side note using "magic numbers" is a bad habit, always refer to length or size of what you are looping

Comment: Yes, thats true, I can more improve this code, but I only removed 2 array. He can define some constant variables such as ROW_INDEX and COLUMN_INDEX. Thank you

Comment: thanks, this solves one of my problems. thIs there a way i can move around the board starting at 0,0 for example? Like the knight(in this case) is supposed to visit every square once, after playing around with the edit you gave i can't seem to do that. Any thoughts on this?